# Share query result between two SSRS datasets

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a fairly large query that I'm using in an SSRS report. The query ultimately has two separate "final" SELECT statements that I would like to use to create two different tables in the SSRS report, and they both depend on data generated by the SQL further up in the report.

What is the common strategy for having two separate datasets that "extend" a common SQL query, is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Create a superset of the 2 queries. You don't say whether you apply additional filtering or additional columns your the final query, but either way you can include the extra information, ctedtd a single query and then filter/display in your 2 different display tables.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use a temp table and return one set of results in the initial dataset and then another dataset from the same temp table. The *Use Single Transaction* checkbox should be checked on the data source to keep the temp table while the second dataset runs.